# Add conditional field using R tidyverse

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse

Here is some data

```
a<-1:5
testing<-tibble(a, b = a * 2)%>%mutate(significant = if_else(a<b,"signi","non"))
```

What I'd like to (which is fairly simple in excel) is to say

=IF(b1 < a$5,"lower",IF(a1 > $b$5,"signi","non"))

How would that work?

sorry for the simple question.

Edit
when the code above is run, a column is added where every value is "signi".
What I'd like to do is compare 
is the value in row 1 column 2 lower than the value in row 5 col 1, if it's lower then lower is the value that goes in row 1 col 3, 
else 
is the value in row 1 column 1 greater than the value in row 5 col 2, if it is then signi is the value that goes in row 1 col 3, otherwise non

I'd like to step through each line in the data frame keeping row 5 col 1 and row 5 col 2 as my reference values.

Comment: Could you please show your expected output?

Comment: In Excel, references such as `b1`, `a$5` and `$b$5` refer to individual cells. The R code processes vectors. Please add details to your question so we can understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If `b` is less than 5 (cell A5) then "lower" else if `a` is greater than 10 (cell B5 which is 2 * cell A5) then "signi" else "non". Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks, edited. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you are after: it is a literal translation of your excel formula into R.

If your initial vector for a extends from 1:11 then you will see "signi" in the `significant` variable assuming the conditions are still 5 and 10.

```r
library(dplyr)

a <- 1:5

testing <- 
  tibble(a, b = a * 2)%>%
  mutate(significant = if_else(b < a[5], "lower", if_else(a > b[5], "signi", "non")))

testing
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>       a     b significant
#>   <int> <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1     1     2 lower      
#> 2     2     4 lower      
#> 3     3     6 non        
#> 4     4     8 non        
#> 5     5    10 non
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Great! This looks like it works in the real data and the test data provided. Thanks. So it's col name then row number in the format name [6]. GREAT! that's really simple